# why did wait4() get replaced by waitpid()

Tags: c, linux, wait, system-calls, waitpid

I was going through the documentation of the system call [`wait4()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) and in its man page it is written

> These functions are obsolete; use `waitpid(2)` or `waitid(2)` in new programs.

So, I went through the documentation of [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and I saw that there is a difference between the two.

[`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) does the same things as [`wait4()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html), but [`wait4()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html), according to the man page,

> additionally return resource usage information about the child in the structure pointed to by `rusage`.

The two system calls are defined as follows

```
pid_t wait4(pid_t pid, int *status, int options, struct rusage *rusage);

pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

Now, I also read that there is a another system call that does that extra job of getting the `rusage` of the child and that is [`getrusage()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html).

So, I can understand that what `wait4()` could do, one can do the same thing by using a combination of `waitpid()` and `getrusage()`.

---

But, what I am not understanding is, there is always a strong reason for making a system call obsolete. But in this case it feels that the functionality has been split.

- If I want to use the combination of `waitpid()` and `getrusage()`, I
  have to check the return values twice, which was not the case for
  `wait4()`.
- Additionally one can use `wait4()` to get `rusage` of a specific
  child, but `waitpid()` would gives `rusage` of all its children
  together (if used with `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`). That sounds like extra overhead if there are more then few child processes.

Why was `wait4()` made obsolete? It seems like it made things harder.

Comment: Performance perhaps? Sometimes you do not want to get resource usage. Also better to have a function just do one thing.

Comment: @EdHeal, But there is a way to use `wait4()` without getting `rusage`. One has to make the last parameter `NULL`.

Comment: @Haris Now I wonder which "rusage()" function `wait4()` is using since it's not accessible via the standard `rusage()` function. I know that we can find the info in the `/proc` file system, but I'd say that's even worse!

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of standardization and history. `wait4` is a 4.3BSD system call, but POSIX.1 retained `waitpid`.

Comment: retained? Is `waitpid()` also an old system call or was it introduced later?

Comment: Can't remember exactly but both are old. If think waitpid is a litlle bit more recent than wait3/wait4??? It was very common at this time that BSD leads innovation, POSIX standardization was a difficult task...

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html:

```
The waitpid() function shall be equivalent to wait() if the pid argument is 
(pid_t)-1 and the options argument is 0. Otherwise, its behavior shall be 
modified by the values of the pid and options arguments
```

so the waitpid() function is provided for three reasons:

```
To support job control

To permit a non-blocking version of the wait() function

To permit a library routine, such as system() or pclose(), to wait for its 
children without interfering with other terminated children for which the 
process has not waited
```

And it also include all previous abilities of wait() as explained

Comment: I think the reasons mentioned can also be achieved using `wait()` variants.